# Component appearance only after file selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is a button on my website page that allows the user to select a file from their device.

Next, I display the file name in a special box, where the user is prompted to convert this file to the desired format.

However, this box, in which the file is displayed, is always present on the page (in the code below, this box is placed in the Card component).

I would like this box to appear only when the user selects a file. And if the user wants to cancel the action, then he could close this box (icon CloseIcon in my code).

Tell me how can this be done?

```
export default function DisplaySelectedFile() {
    const [fileName, setFileName] = useState("");
    return (
        <div>
            <SelectFileButton setFileName={setFileName} />

                <Card sx={styles.CommonStyle}>
                    <Stack spacing={10} direction="row" style={{paddingTop: "20px", paddingLeft: "10px"}}>
                        <div>{fileName}</div>

                        <Stack spacing={3} direction="row">
                            <div>Convert to</div>
                            <ConvertToFormatFile></ConvertToFormatFile>
                        </Stack>

                        <Button>CONVERT</Button>
                        <CloseIcon/>
                        
                    </Stack>
                </Card>
            
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: The standard approaches are using either `&&` for a single truthy check or a ternary operator `boolean ? truthyResult : falsyResult` when you also want to display something different for falsy values.

Comment: You have to conditionally render it depending on whether `fileName` is set or not. Something like `{ fileName ? (/*your component here*/) : null }` or `{fileName && (/* your component here */) || null}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the length if the `fileName` and show the card

```js
{fileName && <Card sx={styles.CommonStyle}>
        <Stack
          spacing={10}
          direction="row"
          style={{ paddingTop: '20px', paddingLeft: '10px' }}
        >
          <div>{fileName}</div>

          <Stack spacing={3} direction="row">
            <div>Convert to</div>
            <ConvertToFormatFile></ConvertToFormatFile>
          </Stack>

          <Button>CONVERT</Button>
          <CloseIcon />
        </Stack>
      </Card>}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Yes it works. But could you tell me how can I make it so that the user can close this component by clicking on the CloseIcon

Comment: `CloseIcon` is a different component , so on click of the button emit an event from that component to the parent component and use `setFileName` to set `fileName` to false

Comment: The point is that I add the following code: <CloseIcon onClick={() => setFileName(false)}/> . Everything is closed. But if i click the button again and select the file, the DisplaySelectedFile component does not open